# How to config power DNS to resolve both aws internal and company internal at a time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, powerdns

I've configured PowerDNS server to check with company's internal DNS and Pointed DHCP options of VPC to PowerDNS server address. But, I'm unable to resolve AWS internal DNS with that. Tried configuring AWS DNS server address in PowerDNS, but no use.

```
/etc/pdns-recursor/recursor.conf
setgid=pdns-recursor
setuid=pdns-recursor
serve-rfc1918=no
local-address=0.0.0.0
forward-zones=domainname=*.*.*.*;169.254.169.253
```

where *.*.*.* is company's internal DNS and  169.254.169.253 is AWS DNS server.

Comment: Have you tried using the DNS server at the "second" ip in the vpc, per this documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html)?

"For example, if the CIDR range for your VPC is 10.0.0.0/16, the IP address of the DNS server is 10.0.0.2."

Comment: Yep, I've tried. When i'm adding both ip's in DHCPOptions Set it is identifying only AWS internal one and not sure what to give as domain name (Internal company domain or AWS domain) ?

Comment: Oh, I mean in your powerDNS configuration. You have 169.254.169.253 there. I would try replacing that. With linux, i would expect that the second DNS server in the DHCPOptions Set is only used if the first one is tried and fails.

Comment: my CIDR block is 10.0.0.0/8 and tried adding forward-zones=nike.com=*.*.*.*;10.0.0.2. No luck, it is still working with internal DNS only, for AWS it is returning following error. 
** server can't find *.*.*.*.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN

Comment: The \*.\*.in-addr.arpa domain refers to a domain used for reverse DNS. You may need to make sure that your reverse zones exist if you're testing for that.

Comment: In your configuration, I'm not sure what \*.\*.\*.\* refers to. I would try putting the aws dns server as the first entry in that part of the forward-zones line

Comment: The way reverse dns works for IPv4 is by flipping the order of the octets in the address and adding in-addr.arpa. For example, looking up the reverse dns for 10.2.3.4 would do a DNS lookup for 4.3.2.10.in-addr.arpa. So, if I had a 2.10.in-addr.arpa. zone configured, I would be able to create and look for a reverse entry there. Unfortunately I'm not a PDNS expert, so I don't know if PDNS has specific functionality for reverse lookups. Good luck!

Comment: enabled reverse dns in PDNS recursor, it is working fine. but still not able to figure out AWS dns resolution.